# GROUP BY parentId and MAX childId

Tags: mysql, group-by, database-design

My tables are below:

**crm_conversions**

[image: crm_conversions]
**crm_messages_of_conversions**
[image: crm_messages_of_conversions]
**crm_receivers_of_messages**
[image: crm_receivers_of_messages]
I want to get all of conversions of an user with only last message. I'm trying to get with the query:

```
SELECT `conv`.`subject`, `mc`.`message_text`, `mc`.`sentDateTime`, `mc`.id AS "msgId", `conv`.id AS "convId"
FROM (`crm_receivers_of_messages` rm)
JOIN `crm_messages_of_conversions` mc ON `mc`.`id` = `rm`.`m_id`
JOIN `crm_conversions` conv ON `conv`.`id` = `mc`.`conv_id`
WHERE `rm`.`receiver_id` =  '1' 
GROUP BY convId
HAVING MAX(msgId)
```

But that query does not to give me true result:
[image: result]
I wanna to get msgId = 1 of convId 1, msgId = 4 of convId = 2

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
SELECT `conv`.`subject`, `mc`.`message_text`, `mc`.`sentDateTime`, `mc`.id AS "msgId", `conv`.id AS "convId"
FROM (`crm_receivers_of_messages` rm)
JOIN `crm_messages_of_conversions` mc ON `mc`.`id` = `rm`.`m_id`
JOIN `crm_conversions` conv ON `conv`.`id` = `mc`.`conv_id`
WHERE `rm`.`receiver_id` =  '1' AND mc.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM crm_messages_of_conversions WHERE conv.id = crm_messages_of_conversions.conv_id)
GROUP BY convId
```

Comment: And what happens if you remove the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: return same result. you are very careful thanks :)